# formset validates to True even if no data provided

Tags: django, django-forms

here is how I'm testing formset:

```
>>>data = {'pfix-0-fname':'','pfix-0-lname':'','pfix-0-relation':'','pfix-0-dob_month':'','pfix-0-dob_day':'','pfix-0-dob_year':'','pfix-1-fname':'','pfix-1-lname':'','pfix-1-relation':'','pfix-1-dob_month':'','pfix-1-dob_day':'','pfix-1-dob_year':'','pfix-INITIAL_FORMS':'0','pfix-TOTAL_FORMS':'2'}
>>>ffact = formset_factory(Form,extra=2)
>>>fset = ffact(data,prefix='pfix')
>>>fset.is_valid()
True
>>>fset.cleaned_data
[{},{}]
```

But if i provide any wrong data in onefield then validation is working for that form.All my fields were made required=True even then it din't help.Any ideas why this is so.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the reason but it worked fine.
setting the relation field's initial to current date did solve the issue.
I think setting any of the fields should make it work but i preferred this one as its not apt type for that field and triggers errors and is not something displayed.